# cx_Oracle connection by python3.5

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I've tried several attempt to connect Oracle DB but still unable to connect. Following is my code to connect. However, I could connect Oracle DB through the terminal like this:
$ sqlplus64 uid/passwd@192.168.0.5:1521/WSVC

- My evironment: Ubuntu 16.04 / 64bit / Python3.5

I wish your knowledge and experience associated with this issue to be shared. Thank you.

```
import os
os.chdir("/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib")
import cx_Oracle  

# 1st attempt      
ip = '192.168.0.5'
port = 1521
SID = 'WSVC'
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, SID)
# dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(ip, port, service_name=SID) 

db = cx_Oracle.connect('uid', 'passwd', dsn_tns)
cursor = db.cursor()

------------------------------------------------- 
# 2nd attempt  
conn = "uid/passwd@(DESCRIPTION=(SOURCE_ROUTE=OFF)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.0.5)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=WSVC)(SRVR=DEDICATED)))"

db = cx_Oracle.connect(conn)
cursor = db.cursor()

------------------------------------------------------ 
# ERROR Description 

cx_Oracle.InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle
```

Comment: What version of cx_Oracle are you using? What environment variables do you have set (LD_LIBRARY_PATH, ORACLE_HOME). The os.chdir() should not be present in any case!

Comment: I'm using cx_Oracle: 5.3. Also I've set in the ~/.bashrc file following :  --------ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
             export PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64:$PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "unable to acquire Oracle environment handle" is due to your Oracle configuration being incorrect. A few things that should help you uncover the source of the problem:

- when using Instant Client, do NOT set the environment variable ORACLE_HOME; that should only be set when using a full Oracle Client or Oracle Database installation
- the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH should contain the path which contains libclntsh.so; the value you selected looks like it is incorrect and should be /usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib instead
- you can verify which Oracle Client libraries are being loaded by using the ldd command as in `ldd cx_Oracle.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I solved the problem with your help. I've added '/lib' directory to the value of LD_LIBRARAY_PATH as you said.